# flubber or animejs for svg animation

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

What are the advantages / disadvantages of using flubber / animejs **to morph svg paths**?

Flubber seems a lot more bulkier (in terms of [bundle size](https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=flubber@0.4.2)) compared to [animejs's](https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=animejs@3.1.0). Whats does flubber do with all that code? Is it more significantly more performant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flubber **and** animeJS are often used together:

```js
/*Ref: from https://www.codeseek.co/asistapl/morph-svg-with-animejs-flubberjs-vZGoOK */
const star = document.querySelector('.js-star')
const target = document.querySelector('.js-target')

const interpolator = flubber.interpolate(
  star.getAttribute('d'),
  target.getAttribute('d')
)

let val = { prop: 0 }

anime({
  targets: val,
  prop: 1,
  duration: 1000,
  easing: 'easeInOutCirc',
  loop: true,
  direction: 'alternate',
  update(anim) {
    star.setAttribute('d', interpolator(val.prop))
  }
})
```

```html
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Morph SVG with anime.js + flubber.js</title>
  
  
  
  
  
</head>

<body>

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="300">
  <defs>
    <path class="js-target" d="M7 2v11h3v9l7-12h-4l4-8z"/>
  </defs>
  <g transform="scale(10)">
    <path class="js-star" d="M12 17.27L18.18 21l-1.64-7.03L22 9.24l-7.19-.61L12 2 9.19 8.63 2 9.24l5.46 4.73L5.82 21z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.0/anime.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/flubber'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Other than that **flubber**:

> The goal of this library is to provide a best-guess interpolation for
>   any two arbitrary shapes

If you take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/veltman/flubber/blob/master/build/flubber.js) you'll see that is full of algorithms aimed to *guess* the best interpolation to be applied. **This task is not trivial**.

While AnimeJs scope is simply to animate value interpolation and apply right values to transition with a lightweight library:

> Anime.js (/ˈæn.ə.meɪ/) is a lightweight JavaScript animation library
>   with a simple, yet powerful API. It works with CSS properties, SVG,
>   DOM attributes and JavaScript Objects.